# Dockerfile PATH variables

Tags: windows, docker, ant, dockerfile, environment-variables

I have some problems running my Dockerfile... 
It looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
USER ContainerAdministrator
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'Continue';"]
RUN mkdir "C:/apache-ant-1.10.13"
RUN mkdir "C:/Project"
COPY "/CustomJDK/" "C:/jdk/"
COPY "/PROJECT/" "C:/Project/"
COPY "/apache-ant-1.10.13/" "C:/apache-ant-1.10.13/"

ENV ANT_HOME=C:/apache-ant-1.10.13
ENV JAVA_HOME=C:/jdk

ENV PATH=%ANT_HOME%/bin;%PATH%
ENV PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%

WORKDIR %PROJECT_HOME%
RUN ["cmd", "/C", "C:/apache-ant-1.10.13/bin/ant -buildfile build.xml"]
COPY ["C:/Project/dist/project.ear", "C:/EAR"]
```

And I have a problem at the last RUN step - 'ant' is not recognized...

```
Step ~~/~~: RUN ["cmd", "/C", "ant -buildfile build.xml"]
 ---> Running in 14cda2b05e87
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The command 'cmd /C ant -buildfile build.xml' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I have actually given the env variable - ant/bin  to the PATH and it should be recognized. 
What is wrong?

Comment: Try these:
ENV PATH=${ANT_HOM}/bin;%PATH%
ENV PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin;%PATH%

Comment: I think for Windows im may not work

Answer (score 0):

try changing the ENV statements to use backslashes instead of forward slashes, as Windows uses backslashes for directory paths:

```
ENV ANT_HOME=C:\apache-ant-1.10.13
ENV JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk

ENV PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
ENV PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```